# How can i animate "swing"synced to music?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, drivers, audio, fcurves

I'm animating with audio baked to f-curves and applying that translation data to an empty hook object using basic drivers to deform geometry. Easy enough to make the "hips" bump to one direction or the other (left or right) in time with the bass drum, but I want to make them "swing" *from* left to right. Effectively I need to reverse to f-curve on every other beat. Is this best accomplished with the driver? (I'm python illiterate) or geo nodes? (Semi literate but not having any luck) or do I need to manipulate the f-curve itself? Please help.

Comment: Did you take a look at the *Sound to Samples* tool https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/channels/editing.html#sound-to-samples ?

Comment: I have already baked the sound wave ti the x location channel of the target object. But that just makes the object move to the positive x with each beat. I want it to alternaten pos x, neg x so that it swings back and forth to the beat. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah I see, basically turning *abs(sin(x))* to *sin(x)*. No idea right now but there must be a simple solution.